# How can I send form_id to javascript function as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dropdown, multi-select

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Başlıksız Belge</title>
 <style>
body
{
  font-family: Open sans, Helvetica;
  background: #111;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
}

h1
{
  font-weight: lighter;
}

small
{
  color: firebrick;
}

div.checkbox_select
{
  width: 200px;
}

.checkbox_select_anchor
{
  display: block;
  background: firebrick;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 5px 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.checkbox_select_anchor:after
{
  width: 0; 
 height: 0; 
 border-left: 10px solid transparent;
 border-right: 10px solid transparent;
 border-top: 10px solid darkred;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 15px;
}

.expanded .checkbox_select_anchor:after
{
 border-top: 0;
 border-bottom: 10px solid firebrick;
}


.checkbox_select_anchor:hover
{
  background: #FF3030 !important;
}

.expanded .checkbox_select_anchor
{
    background: #7C1818;
}

div.checkbox_select .select_input
{
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.checkbox_select_dropdown
{
    display: none;
    background: whitesmoke;
}

.checkbox_select_dropdown.show
{
    display: block;
}

.checkbox_select_dropdown ul
{
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
      border: 1px solid #999;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.checkbox_select_dropdown ul li
{
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    color: #666;
}
.checkbox_select_dropdown ul li label
{
  position: relative;
      padding: 10px 5px 5px 40px;
     display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.checkbox_select_dropdown ul li label:hover
{
  background: #cbcbcb;
  color: white;
}
.checkbox_select_dropdown ul li input:checked + label
{
  background: #bbb;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(150, 150, 150, 1);
}
.checkbox_select_dropdown ul li input
{
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  z-index:1;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30px;
}
.checkbox_select_search
{
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px 5px 5px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
      border-top: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

.checkbox_select_submit
{
    background: #00A600;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 5px 5px;
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.hide
{
    display: none;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
 <h1>multiselect</h1>
//here I have an form id and it is used javascript function
<form id="make_checkbox_select">

  <select name="Cinsiyet">
      <option data-count="(2)" value="Kadin">Kadın </option>
      <option data-count="(23)" value="erkek">Erkek </option>
  </select>
  
  <input type="submit" />
  
</form>

</body>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>

 $(function()
 {
  var mySelectCheckbox = new checkbox_select(
  {
   selector : "#make_checkbox_select",
            selected_translation : "seçildi",
            all_translation : "Tamamı Seçildi",
            not_found : "Bulunamadı",

   // Event during initialization
   onApply : function(e)
   {
                alert("Custom Event: " + e.selected);
   }
  });
  
 });
  
 
// variable_names
// functionNames
// CONSTANT_VARIABLE_NAMES
// $_my_jquery_selected_element

if(typeof String.prototype.trim !== 'function') {
    
    String.prototype.trim = function()
    {
        return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    }
}

var checkbox_select = function(params)
{
    // Error handling first
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    var error = false;

    // If the selector is not given
    if(!params.selector) {                                              console.error("selector needs to be defined"); error = true; }

    // If the selector is not a string
    if(typeof params.selector != "string") {                            console.error("selector needs to be a string"); error = true; }

    // If the element is not a form
    if(!$(params.selector).is("form")) {                                console.error("Element needs to be a form"); error = true; }

    // If the element doesn't contain a select
    if($(params.selector).find("select").length < 1) {                  console.error("Element needs to have a select in it"); error = true; }

    // If the element doesn't contain option elements
    if($(params.selector).find("option").length < 1) {                  console.error("Select element needs to have an option in it"); error = true; }

    // If the select element doesn't have a name attribute
    if($(params.selector).find('select').attr('name') == undefined) {   console.error("Select element needs to have a name attribute"); error = true; }

    // If there was an error at all, dont continue in the code.
    if(error)
        return false;

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    var that            = this,
        $_native_form   = $(params.selector),
        $_native_select = $_native_form.find('select'),
        
        // Variables
        selector                = params.selector,
        select_name             = $_native_select.attr('name').charAt(0).toUpperCase() + $_native_select.attr('name').substr(1),
        selected_translation    = params.selected_translation   ? params.selected_translation   : "selected",
        all_translation         = params.all_translation        ? params.all_translation        : "All " + select_name + "s",
        not_found_text          = params.not_found              ? params.not_found              : "No " + select_name + "s found.",
        currently_selected      = [],
        
        // Create the elements needed for the checkbox select
        $_parent_div    = $("<div />")      .addClass("checkbox_select"),
        $_select_anchor = $("<a />")        .addClass("checkbox_select_anchor")     .text( select_name ),
        $_search        = $("<input />")    .addClass("checkbox_select_search"),
        $_submit        = $("<input />")    .addClass("checkbox_select_submit")     .val("Apply") .attr('type','submit') .data("selected", ""),
        $_dropdown_div  = $("<div />")      .addClass("checkbox_select_dropdown"),
        $_not_found     = $("<span />")     .addClass("not_found hide")             .text(not_found_text),
        $_ul            = $("<ul />"),

        updateCurrentlySelected = function()
        {
            var selected = [];

            $_ul.find("input:checked").each(
                                                        
                function()
                {
                    selected.push($(this).val());
                }
            );

            currently_selected = selected;

            if(selected.length == 0)
            {
                    $_select_anchor.text( select_name )
            }
            else if(selected.length == 1)
            {
                $_select_anchor.text( selected[0] + " " + selected_translation );
            }
            else if(selected.length ==  $_ul.find("input[type=checkbox]").length)
            {
                $_select_anchor.text( all_translation );
            }
            else
            {
                $_select_anchor.text( selected.length + " " + selected_translation );
            }
        },

        // Template for the li, will be used in a loop.
        createItem  = function(name, value, count)
        {
            var uID             = 'checkbox_select_' + select_name + "_" + name.replace(" ", "_"),
                $_li            = $("<li />"),
                $_checkbox      = $("<input />").attr(
                                        {
                                            'name'  : name,
                                            'id'    : uID,
                                            'type'  : "checkbox",
                                            'value' : value
                                        }
                                    )
                                    .click(

                                        function()
                                        {
                                            updateCurrentlySelected();
                                        }
                                    ),

                $_label         = $("<label />").attr('for', uID),
                $_name_span     = $("<span />").text(name).prependTo($_label),
                $_count_span    = $("<span />").text(count).appendTo($_label);
                        
            return $_li.append( $_checkbox.after( $_label ) );
        },
  
  apply = function()
  {
   $_dropdown_div.toggleClass("show");
   $_parent_div.toggleClass("expanded");
    
   if(!$_parent_div.hasClass("expanded"))
   {  
    // Only do the Apply event if its different
    if(currently_selected != $_submit.data("selected"))
    {
     $_submit.data("selected" , currently_selected);

     that.onApply(
      { 
       selected : $_submit.data("selected")
      }
     );
    }  
   }     
  };
    
    // Event of this instance
    that.onApply = typeof params.onApply == "function" ? 
                
                    params.onApply :
                
                    function(e) 
                    {
                        //e.selected is accessible
                    };

    that.update = function() 
    {
        $_ul.empty();
        $_native_select.find("option").each(

            function(i)
            {
                $_ul.append( createItem( $(this).text(), $(this).val(), $(this).data("count") ) );
            }
        );

        updateCurrentlySelected();
    }

    that.check = function(checkbox_name, checked) 
    {
        //$_ul.find("input[type=checkbox][name=" + trim(checkbox_name) + "]").attr('checked', checked ? checked : false);

  $_ul.find("input[type=checkbox]").each(function()
  {
   // If this elements name is equal to the one sent in the function
   if($(this).attr('name') == checkbox_name)
   {
    // Apply the checked state to this checkbox
    $(this).attr('checked', checked ? checked : false);
    
    // Break out of each loop
    return false;
   }
  });
  
        updateCurrentlySelected();

    }

    // Build mark up before pushing into page
    $_dropdown_div  .prepend($_search);
    $_dropdown_div  .append($_ul);
    $_dropdown_div  .append($_not_found);
    $_dropdown_div  .append($_submit);
    $_dropdown_div  .appendTo($_parent_div);
    $_select_anchor .prependTo($_parent_div);

    // Iterate through option elements
    that.update();

    // Events 

    // Actual dropdown action
    $_select_anchor.click( 

        function()
        {
            apply();
        }
    );
             
    // Filters the checkboxes by search on keyup
    $_search.keyup(

        function()
        {
            var search = $(this).val().toLowerCase().trim();

            if( search.length == 1 )
            {
                $_ul.find("label").each(

                    function()
                    {
                        if($(this).text().toLowerCase().charAt(0) == search.charAt(0))
                        {
                            if($(this).parent().hasClass("hide"))
                                $(this).parent().removeClass("hide");

                            if(!$_not_found.hasClass("hide"))
                                $_not_found.addClass("hide");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(!$(this).parent().hasClass("hide"))
                                $(this).parent().addClass("hide");

                            if($_not_found.hasClass("hide"))
                                $_not_found.removeClass("hide");
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
            else
            {
                // If it doesn't contain 
                if($_ul.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(search) == -1)
                {
                    if($_not_found.hasClass("hide"))
                        $_not_found.removeClass("hide");
                }
                else
                {
                    if(!$_not_found.hasClass("hide"))
                        $_not_found.addClass("hide");
                }
                    
                $_ul.find("label").each(

                    function()
                    {
                        if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1)
                        {
                            if($(this).parent().hasClass("hide"))
                                $(this).parent().removeClass("hide");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(!$(this).parent().hasClass("hide"))
                                $(this).parent().addClass("hide");
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    );

    $_submit.click(
                
        function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();

            apply();
        }
    );

    // Delete the original form submit
    $(params.selector).find('input[type=submit]').remove();

    // Put finalized markup into page.
    $_native_select.after($_parent_div);

    // Hide the original element
    $_native_select.hide();
};
</script>
</html>
```

/*I want to use more than one form_id so I will send different paramaters to function. In the function we have selector:"#make_checkbox_select" it takes form id with # sign. And I want to send a parameter to it. I tried to 
fucntion(id)
{selector: id,
.........
}
but it doesn't work.
How I can use this function for using 3 multiselect checkbox?*/

Comment: For all i know ID's in dom can not be duplicated and needs to be unique, but will resulting in weird behaviours. Try using class selectors from there get all the values.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple example - how you can pass parameter to the form submit handler:

```js
var onFormSubmit = function(formId) {
  alert('submit: id = ' + formId);
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" onsubmit="onFormSubmit('form1')">
  <input type="text" name="inputText" value="text1"/>
  <button type="submit">Submit form1</button>
</form>
<form id="form2" onsubmit="onFormSubmit('form2')">
  <input type="text" name="inputText" value="text2"/>
  <button type="submit">Submit form2</button>
</form>
```